# How to access JSON object properties

Tags: javascript, json

I cannot access my JSON object properties.  Given this constructor

```
contractorTestQuestion = function (id, question, multianswer, textanswer, order) {
    var cntrQuestion;
    this.initialize(id, question, multianswer, textanswer, order);
}

$.extend(contractorTestQuestion.prototype, {
    initialize: function (_i, _q, _m, _t, _o) {
          cntrQuestion = {
            "questid" : _i,
            "question": _q,
            "multianswer": _m,
            "textanswer": _t,
            "order": _o,
            "answers": [],
            "change": 'none'
        }
    },
    addAnswer: function (a) {
        answers.push(a);
    },
    getAnswer: function (idx) {
        return this.answers[idx];
    }
});
```

I then create it in my code like this:
var cq = new contractorTestQuestion(qid, q, m, t, tqQuesPos);

what I want to do is cq.question and be able to get the value stored in that field.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Is that jQuery's extend method I see that is being used?  Might want to tag the question with jquery as well.

Comment: Is that JSON I see? Err, [no](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Might want to remove the references to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just set the properties of `contractorTestQuestion` by adding it to a private variable.

Set the properties on `this` like:

```
initialize: function (_i, _q, _m, _t, _o) {
    this.questid = _i;
    this.question = _q;
    this.multianswer = _m;
    this.textanswer = _t;
    this.order = _o;
    this.answers = [];
    this.change = 'none';
},
```

Also, this has nothing to do with [JSON](http://json.org/) which is a data format.